# Bypass varnish cache in my own module

Tags: magento, caching, plugins, varnish

I'm trying to fetch fresh content from a magento website that uses varnish on server side. My plugin works like this:

- when a user clicks a button, it calls a controller that builds the session ID
- from outside I get this session ID and recall the user's cart. The session ID changes accordingly to the user, but the content of the page remains the same even opening the user link with anonymous browser session.

Is there a way to bypass varnish cache control in my plugin without working on varnish? I don't have access to the server.

Comment: In its default config, varnish won't cache cookied requests.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice for that kind of issue is to actually use a **cache buster**, in a form of a get parameters.

Since Varnish actually rely on the route you use to access a page, a different url that makes you end up on the same page will be treated by Varnish as a brand new page, and it will cache it accordingly.

So http://www.example.com/ is the exact same page as http://www.example.com/?cache_buster=1464645205 but Varnish will just treat those as two different page and two different cache entries.

Please note that the number I used there is a timestamp, easy to generate each time you want to access an uncached version of any page.

As for Magento, since the URL are build in the form http://www.example.com/module_front_nanme/controller_name/action_name/parameter_name_1/value_1/parameter_name_2/value_2, you actually have "route like" get parameters.

And if your goal is to actually have an access to the cart, based on a session id you generate in a specific controller, what I would do is to redirect to the cart with the said session ID as a get parameter

```
/**
 * Please not this is an action that should be done in a controller
 */
public function someExampleAction() { 
    /**
      * I am generating a timestamp here as stated above, 
      * but it could be generated any other way, or you can keep
      * your session id "secret" if that is of any concern for your but
      * couple it with a simple cache buster from a timestamp as I did here
      */

    $sessionId = time();
    /**
      * This will redirect you to 
      * http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/index/cache_buster/1464645205
      */
    $this->_redirect( 'checkout/cart', array( 'cache_buster' => $sessionId ) );
}
```

If you are not in a controller, then you can get the URL with `Mage::getUrl()` quite the same way:

```
/** In any context */
$sessionId = time();
Mage::getUrl( 'checkout/cart', array( 'cache_buster' => $sessionId ) );
```